# How to start a stopwatch after data inserted in database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a stopwatch code that works fine on its own. I'm trying to start and show it once the user has punched in so that it calculates time worked and stop it when the user punch out. I'd like to use that data to then insert in the database. How would I go about doing that?

```
 <?php if($timedata['is_clocked_in'] === 'Yes'):?>
    <h5 style="text-transform: uppercase" class="alert alert-info col-md-4">You Are Clocked In : (time count) </h5>
     <?php elseif($timedata['is_clocked_in'] === 'No'):?>
<button><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Punch In Now</button>
     <?php endif;?>
```

**Markup**

```
<h1><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

**Script**

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Don't use Javascript's setTimeout() function to count seconds.**

I can think of many reasons, but two important ones are:

- Reliability: You completely reliant on the processing in the browser of the visitor.
- Security: The visitor can easily manipulate your code.

You have access to PHP, PHP has access to the clock of the server. Use that. See:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

If you have to use Javascript, then use the date object;

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

You get the seconds passed by storing the time at the start and then subtract this from the stop time.

```
timePassed = stopTime - startTime
```

Comment: Thanks for this but PHP is not really a `live` solution... Plus time in PHP is never local... I need to set timezone to get it right which would require me to write a full class for that since im building something international.

Comment: You only need the time passed, not absolute time, so you don't need local time.

Comment: Okay. Do you mind showing what you are talking about by sharing a snippet of something?

Comment: I've tried to be as clear as I can. This is very basic stuff. I think it is better if you try to work out the rest yourself. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by ajax.

Just start beforeSend the request and call stop method on success state.